# Blogger: Removing Post Text From Blog Gadget

Tags: javascript, templates, blogs, blogger

I have run into another issue I could use some help resolving, again regarding the Blog widget/gadget in Blogger.

As standard the Blogger Blog gadget will show your latest post(s) on the landing page, what I want to do is hide the post entirely so that when you open the title link it will take you to that individual post and show the blog body.

This may be answered elsewhere, either here or online but I cannot find anything that really answers this; whether it be the way I'm wording my question I don't know, either way I apologise if I am repeating a question asked elsewhere.

Anyway here is the coding, from what I can gather, that Blogger uses to call up your blog post:

```
<div class='blog-posts hfeed'>

  <b:include data='top' name='status-message'/>

  <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.isDateStart and not data:post.isFirstPost'>
      &lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:post.isDateStart'>
      &lt;div class=&quot;date-outer&quot;&gt;
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
      <h2 class='date-header'><span><data:post.dateHeader/></span></h2>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:post.isDateStart'>
      &lt;div class=&quot;date-posts&quot;&gt;
    </b:if>
    <div class='post-outer'>
      <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
      <b:include cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;static_page&quot;,&quot;item&quot;}' data='post' name='comment_picker'/>
    </div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and thanked for in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete anyway replace the line `<b:include data='post' name='post'/>` with the next condition. This code will show only the post title on the index pages.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "index"'>
  <b:if cond='data:post.title'>
    <h3 class='post-title'>
      <a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a>
    </h3>
  </b:if>
<b:else/>
  <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was only a segment of the code that I thought was relevant to the topic, apologies for it being incomplete, but thanks for the reply and I will give that a try now.